# Stuck in creating a array for the API response

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have 2 records, I want to show a single record as they have same email ID and different orderId and payments date.I am stuck with this and could not move forward.
Please help me, I really need it.
I do not want to repeat userinfo two times as email and name are repeating, I just want order to come under one array.

```
public function getDashboardData() {
    $return = array();
    $return['userInfo'] = array();
    $temp = array();
    if ( isset($this->data['userInput']) && strlen($this->data['userInput']) > 3 ) {
        $userInput = $this->data['userInput'];
        $bindArr    = ['userInput' => "%".$userInput."%" ];
        $query      = "SELECT ju.id,ju.name,ju.email,ep.date,ep.newDateFormat,ep.packID, FROM joomla_users ju LEFT JOIN examPayments ep ON ep.email = ju.email WHERE ep.phone LIKE :userInput AND ep.isActive=1 GROUP BY ep.id  ";
        $sql = $this->PDO->runQuery($query,$bindArr);
        if($this->PDO->prepRowCount($sql) > 0) {
            while( $row = $this->PDO->prepFetch($sql) ){
                    $temp['name ']  =   $row['name'];
                    $temp['email']  =   $row['email'];
                    $temp['order'][]    =   array(
                                        'date' => array(
                                                    'startDate' => date('jS, F Y',strtotime( $row['date']))
                                        ),
                                        'order' => array(
                                                    'orderID' => $row['orderID']
                                        )
                                        
                                    );
                    $status = TRUE; 
                    array_push($return['userInfo'], $temp);             
            }
            $return['status'] = TRUE;
            return $return;
        }else {
            $return['status'] = FALSE;
            $return['message'] = "No Records Found";
        }
    }else{
        $return['status'] = FALSE;
        $return['message'] = "Data Type Error";
    }
    return $return;
}
```

My Output

```
{
"userInfo": [
    {
        "name\t": "Kunal ",
        "email": "Kunal@gmail.com",
        "order": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "startDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "paymentDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "expiryDate": "7th, August 2019"
                },
                "order": {
                    "orderID": "fsdfdsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsf"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name\t": "Kunal ",
        "email": "Kunal@gmail.com",
        "order": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "startDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "paymentDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "expiryDate": "7th, August 2019"
                },
                "order": {
                    "orderID": "dfdsfsfdsfsdfdsfsdfdfs"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
....
            while( $row = $this->PDO->prepFetch($sql) ){
              // This is the case when you already have recorded 
              //some data for the user with given email. So you have 
              //to just append this order in the order array of that user.
                    
                    if(isset($return['userInfo'][$row['email']])){
                       $return['userInfo'][$row['email']]['order'][] = [
                                        'date' => array(
                                                    'startDate' => date('jS, F Y',strtotime( $row['date']))
                                        ),
                                        'order' => array(
                                                    'orderID' => $row['orderID']
                                        )


                            ];
                    }
                    else{

              // This is the case when you've got this user for the first 
              // time. So you create a new entry with this user's email
              // in $return['userInfo'] array.

                       $return['userInfo'][$row['email']] = [
                            'name' => $row['name'],
                            'email' => $row['email']
                            'order' => [
                                        'date' => array(
                                                    'startDate' => date('jS, F Y',strtotime( $row['date']))
                                        ),
                                        'order' => array(
                                                    'orderID' => $row['orderID']
                                        )


                            ]
                       ];
                       
                    }
            }
         // After the while loop finishes
         $return['status'] = TRUE;
         $return['userInfo'] = array_values($return['userInfo']);
         return $return;
.....
```

Why did I add this in the code before returning?

```
$return['userInfo'] = array_values($return['userInfo']);
```

Before this statement, to get a user's information, you would have to do something like this.

```
$return['userInfo']['user_email'];

this would have give you all the details for the user with given email.
```

Now we had to remove the keys and get the values, i.e the email id keys that we were using to identify unique user. In order to do that we had to use `array_values` function.

The final format that you'll have now is

```
"userInfo": [
    {
        "name": "Kunal ",
        "email": "Kunal@gmail.com",
        "order": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "startDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "paymentDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "expiryDate": "7th, August 2019"
                },
                "order": {
                    "orderID": "fsdfdsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsf"
                }
            },
             {
                "date": {
                    "startDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "paymentDate": "7th, August 2019",
                    "expiryDate": "7th, August 2019"
                },
                "order": {
                    "orderID": "dfdsfsfdsfsdfdsfsdfdfs"
                }
            }

        ]
    },
    {
         'Similar data as above for some user with different email id'
    }
]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218749/discussion-on-answer-by-aashish-gaba-stuck-in-creating-a-array-for-the-api-respo).